# How to find the function $f$ that satisfies $f(x, y) = f(x^{-1}, y^{-1})^{-1}$ and $f(x, y)$ is $\approx$ $average(x, y)$?

Tags: functions, functional-equations, average

Fist of all, I'm a programmer, not a mathematician, and I'm sorry for my non native English. And I'm sorry if the question is not appropriate, it is my first time here. Or if the question has no answer.

I am writing a very complex program in the Scheme language and I'm stuck in a problem. I need a function that satisfies the following condition:

**First condition**

$$
f(x, y) = f(x^{-1}, y^{-1})^{-1} \tag{1}
$$

Well, I know that $f=\times$ or $f=\div$, e.g., can satisfies it.

For example:

if $f=\times$ and

if $x = 5$ and $y = 8$ then:

$$
f(x, y) = f(x^{-1}, y^{-1})^{-1} = 40
$$

But I have an extra condition, which makes it difficult:

**Second condition**

The result of $f(x, y)$ should be aprox. the simple average between them. I.e.:

$$
f(x, y) \approx average(x, y) \tag{2}
$$

Example:

if $x = 5$ and $y = 8$ then $f(x, y) \approx 6+\frac{1}{2}$

Or, **at least** something between $x$ and $y$, i.e.:

$$
min(x, y) < f(x, y) < max(x, y) \tag{2}
$$

So, because of that second condition, I can now discard $f=\times$ and $f=\div$.

$average$ itself does not work as well:

For example:

if $f=average$ and

if $x = 5$ and $y = 8$ then:

$$
average(x, y) = 6+\frac{1}{2}
$$
$$
average(x^{-1}, y^{-1})^{-1} = 6+\frac{2}{13}
$$
so
$$
average(x, y) \neq average(x^{-1}, y^{-1})^{-1}
$$

I have no idea how to solve it the right way, so I did some trial and error. The best I got was this:

$$
f = average\left(average(x, y), average(x^{-1}, y^{-1})^{-1} \right)
$$

The distance between $f(x, y)$ and $f(x^{-1}, y^{-1})^{-1}$ is lower than if I use the $average$, **but it is not zero yet.** Also, it works fine to small numbers like $5$ and $8$, but if I try $x=123$ and $y=888$ e.g., it starts to get too far from the average, although satisfying the condition $min(x, y) < f(x, y) < max(x, y)$, what is fair for me in last case.

In Scheme language (R5RS) this following function should return `#t` for any rational number $x > 0$ and $y > 0$ given the right `fn` I am looking for:

```
(define satisfies (lambda (fn x y)
             (and (= (fn x y)
                     (/ 1 (fn (/ 1 x)
                              (/ 1 y))))
                  (= (fn x y) (fn y x))
                  (> (fn x y) (min x y))
                  (< (fn x y) (max x y)))))
```

Is it possible to solve something like that? Is that too specific? Where should I start?

Thank you.

** **LATE EDIT** **

**Third condition**

$$
f(x, y) = f(y, x) \tag{3}
$$

**Fourth condition (nice to have)**

$$
f(x, y) \in \mathbb{Q}  \tag{4}
$$

**Known facts**

- $x \approx y$
- $x \in \mathbb{Q}$
- $y \in \mathbb{Q}$
- $x > 0$
- $y > 0$

**My final solution**

Thanks to @DanielV and @Macavity:

$$
f(x, y) = \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{xy}) \tag{a}
$$

$$
f(x, y) = \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{x^{-1}y^{-1}})^{-1} \tag{b}
$$

if $min(x, y) < min(x^{-1}, y^{-1})$ then use $(a)$
else $(b)$

Assume in this solution:

- $\sqrt{n}$ is a grotesque approximation $\in \mathbb{R}$ of the real root.
- $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{Q}(x)$ is a function that converts a $\mathbb{R}$ number into $\mathbb{Q}$ number (losing precision, of course). Equivalent to `inexact->exact` function in Scheme language.

Comment: Here is away to construct a function satisfying your first equaition. For one dimension: define any $g(x)$ with $g(1)=1$. Then put $f(x) = g(x)$ if $x\in [0,1]$ and $f(x) = 1/g(1/x)$ if $x\not\in [0,1]$. Then by constuction $f(x)f(1/x)=1$ since if $x\in [0,1]$ then $1/x \not\in [0,1]$ so $f(x)f(1/x) = g(x)/g(x) = 1$. A similar construction can be done in two dimensions. To get the average property right seems hard through...

Comment: Tried the GM, $\sqrt{xy}$?

Comment: Thank you! The average is not *strictly* necessary. It is fair if x < f(x, y) < y

Comment: @Macavity wow! (sqrt (* x y)) is pretty amazing! How did you get that? In my tests does not work, but the difference is *very very close to zero*. Maybe something is wrong with the sqrt fn I am using. Maybe I need a more precise sqrt function.

Comment: Well, I looked for means which satisfied your func equation. GM is close to average, and their difference can be estimated.

Comment: @Macavity thanks and congratulations! Please put it as answer and I will accept that. It works for me. If you want, explain in the answer how did you get that.

Comment: Will wait a while and in case no one has a better suggestion will do so.

Comment: GM suggested above seems like a very good choice. btw we have the following ineqality $\min(x,y) \leq \sqrt{xy} \leq \frac{x+y}{2} \leq \max(x,y)$ so GM will always be smaller than the mean, but larger than the smallest of the two elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You found that

$$f(x, y) = x^{-1}y^{-1} \tag{1}$$

and

$$f(x, y) = x^1y^1 \tag{2}$$

satisfies

$$f(x, y) = f(x^{-1}, y^{-1})^{-1} \tag{3}$$

So the next thing I would check is:

$$f(x, y) = x^ay^b \tag{4}$$

If you put **(4)** into **(3)** you see that it satisfies the condition also.  So we try to find

$$x^ay^b \approx \frac 12 x + \frac 12 y$$

Consider when $x\approx y$, you get:

$$x^{a+b} \approx x^1$$
$$a+b \approx 1$$

So you can approximate your function by

$$f(x, y) = x^ay^{1-a}$$

If you expect $x \approx y$ you can choose $a = 1/2$ for a good approximation: $\boxed{f(x, y) = \sqrt{xy}}$.  If you expect $x \not \approx y$, such as $x = ky$ you can solve:

$$x^a(kx)^{b} = \frac 12 x + \frac 12 kx$$
$$k^bx^{a + b} = \left(\frac 12 + \frac 12 k\right)x^1$$

$$\begin{cases}
k^b = \frac 12 + \frac 12 k \\
a + b = 1
\end{cases}$$

$$\begin{cases}
\ln\left(k^b\right) = \ln\left(\frac{1 + k}{2}\right) \\
a = 1 - b
\end{cases}$$

$$\begin{cases}
b = \frac{\ln(1 + k) - \ln(2)}{\ln(k)} \\
a = 1 - b
\end{cases}$$

So if you assume $x \approx ky$ you can create:

$$\boxed{\begin{align} &f(x, y) = x^ay^b \\ &\text{ for } b = \frac{\ln(1 + k) - \ln(2)}{\ln(k)} \text{ and } a = 1 - b\end{align}}$$

Comment: Great! I didn't realize that before, but in my case $x \approx y$. So, the first aprox. that you and Macavity have proposed to me $f(x, y) = \sqrt{xy}$ works very well to solve my problem. --- But now, I have a collateral effect: the system works only with rational numbers, and using square root I introduce irrational, what brings me another problem that I didn't solve yet. I am thinking in "cut" the number and transform: e.g. 999.999499999875 in 9999994/10000, but not sure yet if it will work to all cases. Is it possible to find a solution that also satisfies $f(x, y) \in\mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: Finally I solved my problem. Thank you for everyone that helped me. If you guys are interested how looks like the "final function" that fits to my problem, I put it here: http://pastebin.com/KcqaKNSk

Comment: Well if $x \approx y$ then there is the trivial solution to $f(x, y) \in \mathbb Q$ which is $f(x, y) = x$.  I'll think more about it later and look at your scheme code.  Btw, in some scheme editors there is a shortcut CONTROL BACKSLASH that let's you type in the $\lambda$ character rather than writing out "lambda".

Comment: @FelipeMicaroniLalli Since we know $f(x, y) = x^ay^b$ is a solution when $a + b = 1$, then try out $a = 2$ and $b = -1$.  That should keep you in $\mathbb Q$ even if it isn't the best approx for the average.

Comment: $f(x, y) = x^2y^{-1}$ does not work for me because $f(x, y) \neq f(y, x)$. I just forget to put this condition because (not sure why) I unconsciously assumed it was a natural consequence to first condition. Accidentally the solution $f(x, y)=\sqrt{xy}$ also satisfies $f(x, y) = f(y, x)$. DanielV, could you please send me an email, I just want to thank you for your effort and useful help.

Comment: $f(x, y) = \max(x, y)^2 \times \min(x, y)^{-1}$

Comment: It does not fit $min(x, y) < f(x, y) < max(x, y)$ e.g.: $f(5, 8) = \frac{64}{5} > max(x, y)$. I will use $\sqrt{xy}$ with a slight modification (see the link on pastebin above). It works for me. --- I could use $f(x, y) = x$ as you suggest (actually it was my first thought) but despite being close, it would favor one side, and my algorithm is about disputes.

Answer (score 0):

After

$$
f(x,y) = x^a y ^b \ \ \ \hbox{and}\ \ \ x^a+y^b = \frac{1}{2}(x+y)
$$

making $y = \lambda x \Rightarrow x^{a+b-1}\lambda^b = \frac{1}{2}(\lambda+1) \Rightarrow x^{a+b-1} = \frac{\lambda+1}{2\lambda^b}$

Making now

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
a+b-1 & = & 0\\
\frac{\lambda+1}{2\lambda^b} & = & 1
\end{array}
\right.
$$

and solving

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
a & = & \frac{\ln(2\lambda)-\ln(\lambda + 1)}{\ln(\lambda)}\\
b & = & \frac{\ln((\lambda+1)/2)}{\ln(\lambda)}
\end{array}
\right.
$$